# React js Error with property 'params' of undefined

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I'm trying to get a id and this error is showing:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'params' of undefined
```

this is link from list.js

```
.
.
.
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
.
.
.

<Link to={`/edit/${item.id}`} > Edit </Link>
.
.
.
```

and this one is component edit.js

```
.
.
.



   import { Link, useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
    .
    .
    .
    const Edit = (props) => {
      .
      .
    const history = useHistory();
    const currentCatId =  props.match.params.id; 

    .
    .
    .
} export default Edit;
```

and the error is here props.match.params.id

what I'm doing wrong??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use useHistory, use [useParams](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Hooks/useparams), In your case:

```
const { currentCatId } = useParams();
```

and dont forget the (**:**):

```
<Route path="/edit/:currentCatId ">
    <Edit/>
</Route>


<Link to={`/edit/${item.id}`} > Edit </Link>
```

Comment: You can't destructure `currentCatId`, should be `id`